# Bootstrap on very small screen not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created a table in html and I am using bootstrap for my webpage. I have assigned col-md-12 and col-xs-12 class to my table. My table works fine in big screen but the table rows exceed the table on small screen. I am using Mozilla Developer tools for responsive web design and my code fails to give desired output on small screen of Iphone 6s. What should I do ? 
The code is as follows :

```
 <table  class="table table-striped tablesorter col-md-12 col-xs-12" id = "favtable" >


  <thead >
          <tr>
             <th>Heading1 </th>
             <th >Heading2</th>
             <th >Heading3</th>
             <th >Heading4</th>
          </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody   id = "favtable2">
 </tbody>
```

Comment: reduce the col number

Comment: show us the problem with code.

Comment: Updated the code

Answer (score 1):

wrap your `table` in one `div` with `class` name `table-responsive`

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped tablesorter" id="favtable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Heading1 </th>
                <th>Heading2</th>
                <th>Heading3</th>
                <th>Heading4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="favtable2">
            <tr>
                <td>Heading1 </td>
                <td>Heading2</td>
                <td>Heading3</td>
                <td>Heading4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4c83kavu/1/